# 2D standardization of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics, standard-deviation

Given an n-by-n matrix $A$, and using only linear transformation on each of the rows and columns of $A$ (total of $2n$ transformations), is there a way to double-standardize a matrix, so that each row and each column have zero mean and unit variance?

---

Define [centering matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centering_matrix) as follow:
$$ C_n = I_n-\frac{1}{n}O_n $$
where $I_n$ is the identity matrix of size $n$ and $O_n$ is an n-by-n matrix of all 1's.

An n-by-n matrix $X$ is called doubly-centered if:
$$ X = C_n X C_n $$

A matrix is doubly centered, iff the mean of each row and each column is $0$.

It's a common practice in many fields to [standardize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling#Standardization) data into zero mean and unit variance, given a set of numbers with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, the following linear transformation will standardize that set:
$$ g(x) = \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma} $$

It's easy to double-center a matrix, using only row/column linear transformation, by subtracting the mean of every row/column and adding back the grand mean of the whole matrix.

It's also easy to standardize all rows (or columns) of a matrix using only $n$ linear transformations, one for each row (see $g(x)$ above).

What I'm trying to do is to simultaneously standardize all rows and columns of a matrix in a similar way, is it possible?

Comment: I assume the problem could be solve iteratively until the error will be as small as desired but it's not the kind of solution I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved iteratively, see [Olshen & Rajaratnam 2010](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/20473354/).  The solution is not unique: the outcome depends on whether you start with rows or columns first.